# Can I see my total amount of badge experience somehow?

Tags: pokemon-go

A friend and I both have a gold badge for a specific gym, and we want to compete for who has gained the most badge experience for that gym.

Can we compare our total amounts of badge experience somehow, given that both of us have a gold badge?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, unlike the other badges, gym badges do not provide specific numbers related to them. The only way to tell progress (and thus earned experience) for a gym badge is via the progress bar, which gives an estimate of the amount of experience required to reach the next badge tier. However, since gold is the highest tier of gym badge, there is no progress bar shown, which means there is no way to quantify the total experience you've earned at any particular gym.

If you want to compare gym stats with a friend, the best way to do so would be to compare your activities at that gym (battles won, berries fed, time defended). Those stats would give you a rough estimate of experience earned at that gym, but since the experience gained from battles at a gym involves the CP of the defending Pokémon, then unless you remember the CP of every Pokémon fought at that gym, you won't have exact numbers.

Comment: The xp from battles is pretty negligible anyway; I can't imagine getting bronze from that alone, much less gold. What about raids, though? That could add up pretty fast. Any way to track those?

Comment: @Kat not that I am aware of, sadly